# In the 1980 Flash Gordon movie, what races and characters from the comics are represented in the tribute scene?

Tags: flash-gordon

In the 1980 movie *Flash Gordon*, when Flash, Dale, and Zarkov first land on Mongo, they are immediately captured and taken to Ming's throne room, where Ming is collecting tributes from all the races of Mongo.  This is the only place where we see Thun in the movie.  (In the comics, Thun is the first friend Flash makes on Mongo and becomes part of the rebellion against Ming.)  While Thun is only seen for about a minute, his role in the original comics and the serials is at least hinted at when Thun bravely attempts to kill Ming.

Of course we see Vultan and Barin, as well as Princess Aura.  There are also a number of other groups represented in the throne room, even if no members of those groups have any lines and some have nothing specific to do.  (For instance, the rather short and wide group has at least one person who kicks the guards when the guards fall near them.)

What groups or characters that are in this scene represent groups or people from the original comics or serials of Flash Gordon?  Are there any groups or characters in this scene that are clearly only in the movie?  (For instance, Klytus is never seen in the original comics or serials, but I suspect some of the groups we see were also not in the originals.)